# How to create an empty collection in cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want users to hide nodes in a cytoscape.js graph but also have a reset function. How should I initialize `hiddenNodes` in the following code? I looked at http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/building--filtering which tells me how to add and remove nodes from a collection but not how to create an empty one.

```
var hiddenNodes = ?

function hide(nodes)
{
 nodes.hide();
 hiddenNodes = hiddenNodes.union(nodes);
}

function reset()
{
 hiddenNodes.show();
}
```

P.S.: The hidden nodes are just a MWE, I know I could do this with selectors also.

P.P.S.: Are there alternative functions for union and difference that change the collection directly or are there only those who return new objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.collection) for collection:
cy.collection() - Get an empty collection

Comment: Thanks! I somehow missed that in the documentation.